# Trouble using Pygame's function pygame.image.load()

Tags: python, pygame

I initially tried something along these lines:

```
import pygame
img = ''
if state == 'state 1':
    img = 'flum.png'
else:
    img = 'flab.png'

flooimage = pygame.image.load(img)
```

but the last line, flooimage = pygame.image.load(img), threw an error saying

```
pygame.error: SDL_RWFromFile(): No file or no mode specified
```

I tried changing the last line to

```
flooimage = pygame.image.load(img, ".png")
```

but it threw the same error. Does anyone know how I might go about getting this to run? Would something along the lines of

```
if state == 'state 1':
    img = pygame.image.load('flum.png')
[...]
flooimage = img
```

work better?

Comment: *Would [..] work better?* Well, you should try and tell us!

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference at all. That only means that the file probably does not exist, or at least isn't in the same folder.

Comment: It's in a diffirent folder, but I put the directory. Like

    img = pygame.image.load('imageFolder\\flum.png')

Answer (score 0):

from the code above you haven't initialized pygame. also the line of code below the error should look like this:

```
  flooimage = pygame.image.load(img + ".png")
```

you should also put str() around the Img variable. like so:

```
flooimage = pygame.image.load(str(img) + ".png")
```

im not sure what your program is going to do but you should load all your images into an array it make it easy to use them.

```
IntAllScreens = [{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]
            for IntAS in range (0,len(self.IntAllScreens)):
                    for IntT in range(0,100):
                                self.IntAllScreens [IntAS][IntT] = pygame.image.load( "Textures\\" + str(Img) + ".png")
```

Comment: Had initialized pygame, forgot to say that in the example snip. The real code is really big and I didn't want to paste it all. The format you suggested worked though, so thanks.